# Python - Optimize Lambda with Numpy Operations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

I'm having difficult time optimizing the following calculation;

```
Inner_diff_grp  = np.var(list(map(lambda x : np.percentile(winw2_grp,x[0]) - np.percentile(winw2_grp,x[1])  ,[(i+7,i) for i in range(0,98,7)])))
```

'winw2_grp' is a small sized image array (say 5x5). I'm looping though the image to find percentile values at every 7th step and then calculating the variance of those values.

Total images in the loop are around 100,000. Earlier I was using standard loops but now I've changed that to Pandas.apply that seems to be performing better and throughput is around 150 iteration/sec now - which still means more than 10mins of runtime.

Appart from trying out pooling to exploit all CPUs, is there any way to optimize this calculation?

Comment: I know pandas is numpy based, but have you tried same thing on pure numpy? maybe numba could help too.

Comment: Thanks Ehsan, it actually solved the issue. I started with a small piece ported to numba, and it jumped to around 350 iter/sec. But once I ported everything to a numba func its now around 4000 iter/sec. Numba is a gem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped. Would be great if you could share your code as solution here, in case someone else faces the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per the sugession from @Ehsan, I enclosed the calculation in a separate function with the numba decorator and that was it. I deliberately removed the lambda because I wanted to try out other optimizations (Parallel execution) - so its not part of the strategy but rather a WIP.

```
@nb.jit(nopython = True, fastmath=True)
def numba_perc_calc(win):
    arr = [0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49, 56, 63, 70, 77, 84, 91, 98]
    perc = np.percentile(win,arr)
    dif = np.diff(perc )
    var_of_percs = np.var(dif )
    return var_of_percs
```

The result of a piece on a smaller test-set is followed.

[image]

Comment: And yes, running the code without loop is pretty fast. I tried using prange but that has its own limitations.